# DOMDocument encoding problems / characters transformed

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument

I am using DOMDocument to manipulate / modify HTML before it gets output to the page. This is only a html fragment, not a complete page. My initial problem was that all french character got messed up, which I was able to correct after some trial-and-error. Now, it seems only one problem remains : ' character gets transformed into ? .

The code :

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
         $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($row->text));

         //Some pretty basic modification here, not even related to text

         //reinsert HTML, and make sure to remove DOCTYPE, html and body that get added auto.
         $row->text = utf8_encode(preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML())));
?>
```

I know it's getting messy with the utf8 decode/encode, but this is the only way I could make it work so far. Here is a sample string :

Input :
Sans doute parce qu’il vient d’atteindre une date déterminante dans son spectaculaire cheminement

Output :
Sans doute parce qu?il vient d?atteindre une date déterminante dans son spectaculaire cheminement

If I find any more details, I'll add them. Thank you for your time and support!

Comment: What character set is `$row->text`?  If it's UTF-8 directly (Assuming it's coming from MySQL you'd need to set the connection charset to UTF8) then you don't need the `utf8_(en|de)code` functions.  Force the charset to UTF8 and all of your problems *should* go away (assuming that's where `$row` comes from)...

Comment: The input is coming from a CMS , all set to utf8 (string, database, and so on).

But it seems like my problem is not what I think it was. I found out that the string that came from me are all OK, and my coworkers' pc too. The problem only occurs when the string is being input by my client's pc. I would bet she's pasting the text from word or whatever and some weird stuff is going on then. I'll have to digg into this.

Comment: Ahhh...  Then perhaps check for UCS-2LE (UTF-16LE) characters (Since that's the default for Word IIRC)...

Answer (score 16):

Don't use `utf8_decode`. If your text is in UTF-8, pass it as such.

Unfortunately, `DOMDocument` defaults to LATIN1 in case of HTML. It seems the behavior is this

- If fetching a remote document, it should deduce the encoding from the headers
- If the header wasn't sent or the file is local, look for the correspondent meta-equiv
- Otherwise, default to LATIN1.

Example of it working:

```
<?php
$s = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
Sans doute parce qu’il vient d’atteindre une date déterminante
dans son spectaculaire cheminement
</body>
</html>
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d = new domdocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);

echo $d->textContent;
```

And with XML (default is UTF-8):

```
<?php
$s = '<x>Sans doute parce qu’il vient d’atteindre une date déterminante'.
    'dans son spectaculaire cheminement</x>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d = new domdocument;
$d->loadXML($s);

echo $d->textContent;
```

Comment: if I remember right I think I used to do the following hacky fix to make sure the html was set to utf8, `$d->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $html);` being that it always seemed to recover so well when parsing invalid html anyway

Comment: @chris I used to do that as well, until it broke recently. The answer is correct, the <meta> tag is required for it to work smoothly; see also: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32547

Comment: YES, THANKS! This is the solution: NOT convert your original UTF8 HTML, only add the tag META. PS: and can be more simple, I tested without HTML root tag, only tags P and starting with this META.

Comment: Why not use utf8_decode? Is it a performance thing? Or is it more a hack than a real solution in your eyes?

Comment: @JosFaber `utf8_decode` will transform all the characters not representable in ISO-8859-1 (which are almost all Unicode characters and includes `’`) into question marks, which is the problem that motivated the question.

Comment: Tx @Artefacto. And tx rambo coder for the working hack!

Comment: @goat - Cheers man, perfect hack to get me through this minor task with an unfortunately inconsistent and unconfigurable default PHP package. :D

Answer (score 8):

`loadHtml()` doesn't always recognize the correct encoding as specified in the Content-type HTTP-EQUIV meta tag.

If the `DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8')` and `loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $html)` hacks don't work as they didn't for me (PHP 5.3.13), try this:

Add another `<head>` section immediately after the opening `<html>` tag with the correct Content-type HTTP-EQUIV meta tag. Then call `loadHtml()`, then remove the extra `<head>` tag.

```php
// Ensure entire page is encoded in UTF-8
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($body);
$body = $encoding ? @iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8', $body) : $body;

// Insert a head and meta tag immediately after the opening <html> to force UTF-8 encoding
$insertPoint = false;
if (preg_match("/<html.*?>/is", $body, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $insertPoint = mb_strlen( $matches[0][0] ) + $matches[0][1];
}
if ($insertPoint) {
    $body = mb_substr(
        $body,
        0,
        $insertPoint
    ) . "<head><meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /></head>" . mb_substr(
        $body,
        $insertPoint
    );
}
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Suppress warnings for loading non-standard html pages
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($body);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

// Now remove extra <head>
```

See this article: http://devzone.zend.com/1538/php-dom-xml-extension-encoding-processing/

Answer (score 4):

This was enough for me, the other answers here were overkill. Given I have an HTML document with an existing HEAD tag. HEAD tags don't have attributes and I had no issues leaving the extra META tag in the HTML for my use-case.

```
$data = str_ireplace('<head>', '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />', $data);
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `DOMDocument` and `LoadHTML` will default to LATIN1 encoding with HTML fragments. It will also wrap your HTML with something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>YOUR HTML</body></html>
```

So also as others have pointed out, you can fix the encoding by inserting a HEAD element into your HTML with a META element that contains the correct encoding.

However, if you're working with an HTML fragment, you probably don't want the wrapping to happen and you also don't want to keep that HEAD element you inserted.

The following code will insert the HEAD element, and then after processing, using regex will remove all the wrapping elements:

```
<?php
$html = '<article class="grid-item"><p>Hello World</p></article><article class="grid-item"><p>Goodbye World</p></article>';
$head = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($head . $html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Loop through all article.grid-item elements and add the "invisible" class to them
$nodes = $xpath->query("//article[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grid-item ')]");
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $class = $node->getAttribute('class');
  $class .= ' invisible';
  $node->setAttribute('class', $class);
}

$content = preg_replace('/<\/?(!doctype|html|head|meta|body)[^>]*>/im', '', $dom->saveHTML());
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

echo $content;
?>
```