# Preserve utf8 when loading HTML from file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, domdocument

Well, apparently, PHP and it's standard libraries have some problems, and DOMDocument isn't an exception.

There are workarounds for `utf8` characters when loading HTML string - `$dom->loadHTML()`.

Apparently, I haven't found a way to do this when loading HTML from file - `$dom->loadHTMLFile()`. While it reads and sets the encoding from `<meta />` tags, the problem strikes back if I haven't defined those. For instance, when loading a fragment of HTML (template part, like, `footer.html`), not a fully built HTML document.

So, how do I preserve utf8 characters, when loading HTML from file, that hasn't got it's `<meta />` keys present, and defining those is not an option?

#### Update

footer.html (the file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM):

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>My sūpēr ōzōm ūtf8 štrīņģ</p>
</div>
```

index.php:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('footer.html');
echo $dom->saveHTML(); // results in all familiar effed' up characters
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your concrete problem? Which encoding has the input data? What is the input data? What fails? Please show a simplified loading procedure with code, so it's more concrete to get answered. By *default* `DOMDocument` supports `utf-8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not sure about how to go about solving the problem with `->loadHTMLFile()`, have you considered using `file_get_contents()` to get the HTML, run `mb_convert_encoding()` on that string, then pass that value in to `->loadHTML()`?

<s>Edit: Also, when you **[initialize DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php)**, are you giving it the $encoding argument?</s>

Comment: The DOMDocument construct options only work for XML. And `$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';` doesn't cut it either. In fact, that's a known problem for DOMDocument.

Comment: Ah. Just saw it as an option. Guess I should have read the description. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try a hack like this one:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
        $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper
```

Several others are listed in the user comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php. It is also important that your document head includea meta tag to specify encoding FIRST, directly after the  tag.

Comment: I've gone through all of those, plus I noted that in question. But, I'm looking for `loadHTMLFile()` method. I'm currently working on to implement @simshaun's answer. Will see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846243/816753 and instead of adding another `<head>`, wrap your entire fragment in

```
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /></head>
    <body><!-- your content here --></body>
</html>`
```

Comment: YES, THANKS! This is the solution: NOT convert your original UTF8 HTML, only add the tag META.  PS: and can be more simple, I tested without HTML root tag, only tags P and starting with this META.

Answer (score 3):

The  key is for your browser only. Once the page is all built up, your browser should display the page correctly if it has the meta at the end.

You can always try to use the utf8_decode (or encode, I'm never sure lol) function before echo'ing the data like so:

```
echo utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML());
```