# ÆØÅ Letters randomly being replaced by Ã¦Ã˜Ã¥

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Yeah, I have an issue with ÆØÅ randomly being replaced with Ã¦Ã˜Ã¥ when loading/refreshing a php page calling on some values...

It worked fine until I added

```
$Filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $Filename);
```

but that caused the script to delete the . in the file extensions, so I removed the code. Now it randomly replaces the letters upon load/refresh

```
$Filename=$_FILES['Filename']['name'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
$Contact=$_POST['Contact'];
$Time = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i');
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$Filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $Filename);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
echo "Filen ". basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']). " er nå lagt til blant Alta Botanikkforeningens funn.";
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("altabotanikk") or die(mysql_error()) ;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO picture (Filename,Description,Contact,Time,Title)
VALUES ('$Filename', '$Description', '$Contact', now(), '$Title')") ;
} else {
echo "Det skjedde noe galt her :/";
}
```

Due to it being random and no errors anywhere, I have no idea what is causing this.

HTML declaring UTF-8

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Your mysql connection does not know you want to talk in UTF8

Comment: Make sure you are using the right encoding for both mysql and html.

Comment: @Basje Nono, it worked fin 100% of the time until I added the mentioned code snippet

Comment: @HanletEscaño I use UTF-8 for MySQL and the PHP documents

Comment: @TheLastMelody does the same happen with different browsers? I am wondering if the strange characters were cached.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yeah, it happens in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: Weird, sorry, could you update your code and show us where/how you are being especific about UTF-8 in your HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you should try this idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/906752/752527 This way, if there is something else messing with it, it might fix it

Comment: @HanletEscaño Nope, no difference :

Comment: Sorry, I am just throwing answers because this is hard to debug without the actual code. Try solutions in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523409/domdocument-encoding-problems-characters-transformed

Comment: @HanletEscaño I can pastebin the actual code, or upload the file somewhere

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31975/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-the-last-melody)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure your MySQL connection is always UTF8?

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
// make sure we're in UTF8 mode!
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
// continue
mysql_select_db("altabotanikk") or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Then take it from there?

Even if your HTML has a `meta` tag for charset utf8, you'll need some more work. Incidentally, the new format for html5 (rather than the now-outdated html4.01) is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

The mysql *connection* also needs to be told that everything is in UTF8. And then for good measure, you also want to make sure your script itself (the .php file) is saved as a unicode file, because yes, that too can mess things up (fun times!)

Comment: Thank you, this caused the "random" issue to disappear, now it only displays the wierd characters, so now I just have to correct the characters in the DB, Thanks ^_^