# prevent PHP's DOMDocument from changing character encoding

Tags: php, domdocument

How do I prevent DOMDocument from changing character encoding?  See the following, and note how `“` is being changed to `â`.

```
<?php
    $message = "<p>Hello “something in quotes” goodby</p>";
    echo("pre message: $message\n");
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($message);
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $message=$doc->saveHTML($body);
    echo("Modified message: $message\n");
```

OUTPUT:

```
pre message: <p>Hello “something in quotes” goodby</p>
Modified message: <body><p>Hello âsomething in quotesâ goodby</p></body>
```

Comment: $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));, copied from the above post and it works

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  Yes it does work.

Comment: no problem :), yeah, i tried few attempts on my own and the answer below, only `mb_conv...` works :S

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems and solved them using iconv and forcing the encoding.

```
$new_string = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$old_string);
```

[here's the php man page on it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

after further investigation it looks like this is a bug in DOM:Document.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32547

Comment: Thanks jbrahy, but no change.

Comment: looks like you have to put the correct meta tag in the html. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=32547

Comment: And here's a similar problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523409/domdocument-encoding-problems-characters-transformed